# Is 回す ever used to mean "gang-rape"?

Tags: words

Sorry, I've been on reddit...and found the eighth definition here:

> 回す
>   まわす 1: to turn; to rotate; to gyrate;
>   2: to circulate; to send around;
>   3: to surround;
>   4: to put something to a new use (e.g. leftovers); 
>   5: () (after the -masu stem of a verb) ... around (i.e. to chase someone around);
>   6: to dial (e.g. telephone number); 
>   7: (Godan verb with su ending) to invest;
>   8: to gang-rape

Is this definition ever used? Is it slang? If it is not asking too much, would someone provide an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A little investigation shows that this can also be written as 輪姦{まわ}す, which appears to be the formal word for gang rape, 輪姦{りんかん}, adapted to the slang term まわす.

I'm going to go on the assumption that the term まわす originated from the idea of 回す (I'll let you go ahead and think about why) and later took on the slangy 輪姦す reading.

See the following for details:

http://www.weblio.jp/content/%E8%BC%AA%E5%A7%A6%E3%81%99